# Regex - Compare two capture groups

Tags: regex

trying to create a regex to limit our spam intake.  Problem is, I'm not exactly fluent in regular expressions.  The product of my work below is mostly copy and paste, tweaks, and searches for things to help tweak it more.

What I've decided I want to try is using a regex to match emails where a link misrepresents the hostname.

For example:

```
<A HREF="http://phishers.org/we_want_your_money.htm">http://someLegitimateSite.com/somewhere </A>
```

I basically only care about the hostnames, to limit false positives and to avoid more or less legitimate links such as A HREF...>click here!

To date, I have this:

```
(HREF="http[s]?:\/\/)(?'hostname1'(.*?))[:|\/|"].*?\"\>(http[s]?:\/\/)(?'hostname2'(.*?))[<|\/|:]
```

According to https://regex101.com/ I have two named capture groups (hostname1 and hostname2), and a whack of other groups that I'm not sure I care about.

What I want to do is match the string if hostname1 and hostname2 are the same.  I get the feeling that it involves either a lookbehind or a lookahead, but I honestly don't know.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Jan for prototyping this.  I, as per the comments in his answer, made one quick addition to add the unaccounted for case of image tags.  In the case of large websites (BestBuy for example) they store their images on a different content server, which was triggering the rule.  I've decided to exclude image tags, which I BELIEVE (in my very non-expert opinion) I have successfully done.  YMMV.

```
href=["']https?:\/\/(?<hostname>[^\/"]+)[^>]+>((?!<IMG).?)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?!.*\k'hostname')
```

Comment: It only involves a backreference. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/mL7kC7/1). However, you might want to switch to a HTML parser to parse your HTML.

Comment: I'm not an html expert, but what do parsers do when they encounter duplicate attribute's ? `<a href="here" href="there">`

Comment: To be more specific, our spam filtering solution allows us to score emails (or other things such as accept/reject, etc) based on a number of criteria.  One such criteria, and what I plan to use is the "Raw Body" "Matches Regular Expression" <regex>.  Unfortunately that removes the possibility of using a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It somewhat depends on your programming language. In PHP you could come up with sth. like:

```
href=["']https?:\/\/(?<hostname>[^\/]+)[^>]+>(?:https?:\/\/)?\k'hostname'
# match href, =, a single/double quote, :// literally
# capture everything up to a forward slash (but not including) in a group called hostname
# followed by anything but >
# followed by >
# start a non capturing group (?:) with http/https://
# look if one can match the previously captured group called hostname
```

If this is the case, it is presumably not a spam link (href and link text match).

**An overview:**

```
<A HREF="http://phishers.org/we_want_your_money.htm">http://someLegitimateSite.com/somewhere </A>
<a href="https://example.com/subfolder">example.com</a> <-- will match, the others not
<a href="http://somebadsite.com">https://somegoodsite.com</a>
```

See a [working example here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eL7oH0/1).

**EDIT:** According to your comment, you want the negated result, this can be done via a negative lookahead:

```
href=["']https?:\/\/(?<hostname>[^\/"]+)[^>]+>(?:https?:\/\/)?(?!.*\k'hostname')
# same as before, except for the last part: (?!...)
# this one assures that the following group (hostname in our case) is not matched
```

See a working example for this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/eL7oH0/2).

Comment: That is VERY close to what I need - I'm experimenting now with ways of negating the results of this as I need the ones which do not match rather than the ones which do.  That way it triggers on the bad emails and applies the score to the ones I wish to have held.

Comment: @NetworkingGuy See my updated answer, you need a negative lookahead then.

Comment: Jan, thank you.  I was putting various ! in various places, however it didn't seem to do the trick.  Looks like a touch more bracketing was needed.

Comment: Jan, I've discovered one particular use-case which I did not account for.  I believe I've accounted for it now.  Image tags as the link "body".        href=["']https?:\/\/(?<hostname>[^\/"]+)[^>]+>((?!<IMG).)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?!.*\k'hostname')

Comment: @Jan Thank you, really helpful. Is there any (alternative) way to the same in VIM? Unfortunately there is no \k...